# If a coin has a 80 % chance of getting heads, independently , what are the chances of getting 4 tails in a row?

Tags: probability

What are the chances of getting $4$ tails in a row ? Also, is there a formula for calculating $x$ tails in a row, $x$ being the number of tails.

Comment: What is the chance of getting one tail in a row? two? $x$?

Comment: the chance of getting one tail in a row would be .20  the question was getting 4 in a row

Comment: Can we presume that the coin cannot land on its miniscule surface?; ie is tails mutually exclusive and exhaustive to the heads outcome. I presume, by independently you mean that its IDD? But any case just use the binomial formula..... – William

Answer (score 3):

Let $p$ be the probability that the coins lands heads (in this case, $p=0.8$). Then, $1-p$ is the probability that the coin will land tails, and, since the tosses are independent, the chance of getting $4$ tails in a row is $(1-p)\cdot (1-p)\cdot (1-p)\cdot (1-p)=(1-p)^{4}$. More generally, the change of getting $x$ tails in a row is $(1-p)^{x}$. So, in your particular case, the change of getting $x$ tails in a row is $0.2^{x}$; in particular, the chance of getting $4$ tails in a row is $0.2^{4}=0.0016$.

Answer (score 1):

Probability of getting one head with your coin is $0.2$, equally $0.2^1$. Probability getting 2 heads is $0.2^2$ and so on. It follows that getting four in a row is $0.2^4$ which equals $0.0016$

Closest you can get to a formula is $0.2^n$ where n is the number of throws.

Answer (score 1):

What is the probability of getting heads? $0.8$

Since the sum of the sample space is $1$ (and this is a discrete distribution), the probability of getting tails must thus be $1 - 0.8 = 0.2$ (unless we're using a three faced coin? four faced? n-faced?)

Thus the probability of getting 4 tails in a row (assuming each throw is independent is) $0.2^n, n = 4$